# Change the HTML div content using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

AngularJs code to display the selecting div content:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Individual</option>
    <option value="2">Business</option>
    <option value="3">Others</option>
</select>
```

If option `Individual` is selected, it must show the **div content** with

```
<div id="individual">
.
.
.
</div>
```

If option `Business` is selected it must show the **div content** with

```
<div id="business">
.
.
.
</div>
```

If option `Others` is selected it must show the **div content** with

```
<div id="others">
.
.
.
</div>
```

Can anyone refer me to any tutorials or link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the ID of a HTML element with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript)

Comment: If your question is not the same as the above one, edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial or guide is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Show div content depending on which option chosen from drop down menu (ng-show/ng-switch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389562/angular-show-div-content-depending-on-which-option-chosen-from-drop-down-menu)

Comment: Thanks....... i got the solution by using `ng-model and ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` to store selected value

```
<select ng-model="selectedVal">
         <option value="0">--Select--</option>
         <option value="1">Individual</option>
         <option value="2">Business</option>
         <option value="3">Others</option>
</select>
```

Then use `ng-switch` to display div accordingly

```
<div ng-switch="selectedVal">
  <div ng-switch-when="1" id="individual">...</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2" id="business">...</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="3" id="Others">...</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>...</div>
</div>
```

Check working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/35068/)

Comment: @MohanaKrishnanS I have added working fiddle. Check that.